# Scroll top using variable

Tags: jquery, variables, scroll, scrolltop

There's a way to use the .scrollTop() with a variable insted a number, I tried to do this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $('#Frame1').height(); 
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > top) {
        $('#icono-menu').css("color", "red");
    }
});
```

but it doesn't seems to work... 
Thanks in advance! i'm kinda new on this things

Comment: Add why it does not seems to work…

Comment: In what way does it not seem to work?

Comment: the item i'm trying to change does not do anything

Comment: use `$(this).offset().top` instead or `$(this).position().top` if it suits your setup better (read up on the difference at jquery.com)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var top = $('#Frame1').height(); 
    // let's set vertical scrollbar position is 300
    if ($(this).scrollTop(300).height() > top) {
        $('#icono-menu').css("color", "red");
    }
});
```